# Not able to access Oracle Spatial Operators

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, geocoding

When i try to use the [Oracle Spatial operators](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_operat.htm#BJAFBCFC), it throws

> ORA-13226: interface not supported without a spatial index.

While with SDO_GEOM procedure, it works fine.
e.g

```
select *
from test_sdo_geometry
where SDO_GEOM.WITHIN_DISTANCE(sdo, 25, SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(151.16567373275757, -33.9031022157086, null), null, null), 0.05, 'unit=M')='TRUE'
order by 1;
```

But with Oracle operator it throws the above error.

```
  select *
from test_sdo_geometry
where SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE(SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(151.16567373275757, -33.9031022157086, null), null, null), SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(151.16567373275757, -33.9031022157086, null), null, null), 'distance=10 unit=M')='TRUE'
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [Oracle 11g Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_operat.htm#SPATL1041), the operator is disabled if the table does not have a spatial index or if the number of dimensions for the query window does not match the number of dimensions specified when the index was created.

Therefore, two steps have to be completed in order to use `SDO_GEOM.WITHIN_DISTANCE`:

1/ You have to update the metadata view named `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA`. This is required before the Spatial index can be created. Examples can be found on [Spatial Data Types and Metadata](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_objrelschema.htm#SPATL486) page.

2/ You have to create a spatial index for the "SDO" field following the instructions provided on SQL Statements for Indexing Spatial Data page:

```
CREATE INDEX TEST_SDO_GEOMETRY_IDX ON TEST_SDO_GEOMETRY (SDO)
INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;
```